# Need to reduce the execution time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

We are trying to execute below script for finding out the occurrence of a particular word in a log file 
Need suggestions to optimize the script.

**Test.log size** - Approx to 500 to 600 MB

$wc -l Test.log

**16609852** Test.log

**po_numbers** - 11 to 12k po's to search

$more po_numbers

```
xxx1335
AB1085
SSS6205
UY3347
OP9111
....and so on
```

**Current Execution Time** - 2.45 hrs

```
while IFS= read -r po
do
check=$(grep -c "PO_NUMBER=$po" Test.log)
echo $po "-->" $check >>list3

if [ "$check" = "0" ]
then
echo $po >>po_to_server
#else break
fi
done < po_numbers
```

Comment: I think you should write a short prog with a hash table

Comment: Could you site an example for the same

Comment: try first loading the Test.log file in memory, then do search/statistic

Comment: Could you provide a reduced example of `po_numbers` and `Test.log` so we can see how it might be sped up.

Comment: Did you consider rewriting your script in some other language (Python, C++,  ...) ?

Answer (score 2):

You are reading your big file too many times when you execute

`grep -c "PO_NUMBER=$po" Test.log`

You can try to split your big file into smaller ones or write your patterns to a file and make grep use it

`echo -e "PO_NUMBER=$po\n" >> patterns.txt`

then

`grep -f patterns.txt Test.log`

Comment: May you please provide more details on the code, How do I segrigate the data i.e. list3 and po_to_server

Comment: po_to_server will contain the same as po_numbers since you are reading the latter line by line and then writing it back to po_to_server. With regards to list3 it contains $po --> <matched string in Test.log> which it's not in a  comfortable format since the right part of the "arrow" could contain several lines. You can generate it by redirecting the output of the last grep in the answer to a file and the parsing it with your code but you could end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -Fwf <(sed 's/.*/PO_NUMBER=&/' po_numbers) Test.log
```

create the lookup file from po_numbers (process substitution) check for literal word matches from the log file.  This assumes the searched PO_NUMBER=xxx is a separate word, if not remove `-w`, also assumes there is no regex but just literal matches, if not remove `-F`, however both will slow down searches.

Comment: thank you for your answer! But it did not work, the query returns no data.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Grep :**

```
sed -e 's|^|PO_NUMBER=|' po_numbers | grep -o -F -f - Test.log | sed -e 's|^PO_NUMBER=||' | sort | uniq -c > list3
grep -o -F -f po_numbers list3 | grep -v -o -F -f - po_numbers > po_to_server
```

**Using awk :**

This awk program might work faster

```
awk '(NR==FNR){ po[$0]=0; next }
     { for(key in po) {
         str=$0
         po[key]+=gsub("PO_NUMBER="key,"",str)
       }
     }
     END { 
       for(key in po) {
          if (po[key]==0) {print key >> "po_to_server" }
          else            {print key"-->"po[key] >> "list3" }
       }
     }' po_numbers Test.log
```

This does the following :

- The first line loads the `po` keys from the file po_numbers
- The second awk parser, will pars the file for occurences of `PO_NUMBER=key` per line. (`gsub` is a function which performs a substitutation and returns the substitution count)
- In the end we print out the requested output to the requested files.

The assumption here is that is might be possible that multiple patterns could occure multiple times on a single line of `Test.log`

Comment: the original order of po_numbers will not be satisfied.

Comment: Expected this to be completed within an hour but  taking more time. for the awk one

Comment: For answer grep – 
This prints the count of po_numbers to file- list3 and the other file- po_to_server is empty.

Comment: @Rasesh, there was a typo in the last one, I have updated the cmd

Comment: Now using grep cmd I get 2 empty files i.e. list 3 and po_to_server within 5sec.

Comment: @Rasesh, I only updated the second CMD. It would be useful if we could see some example input.

Answer (score -1):

"finding out the occurrence"
Not sure if you mean to count the number of occurrences for each searched word or to output the lines in the log that contain at least one of the searched words. This is how you could solve it in the latter case:

```
(cat po_numbers; echo GO; cat Test.log) | \
    perl -nle'$r?/$r/&&print:/GO/?($r=qr/@{[join"|",@s]}/):push@s,$_'
```

Comment: And if either po_numbers or the log contain GO?! I don't think you have thought this through =}

Comment: But GO is the separation word between the search words in `cat po_numbers` and the log in `cat Test.log` to be searched. Don't you see? (And of course the whole thing breaks down if GO, or another chosen separation word, is also a word in po_numbers)

Comment: I just want to know if the particular string i.e. PO_NUMBER=$po is present in the log file.
I dont want to know the count of how many times its present. if the search finds it once then it should move to the next string($po) to search for the next one.